# How would I implement event listeners instead of inline html event handlers in this Javascript example?

Tags: javascript, async-await, scope, event-handling

I was trying to get data from an API that gives me a list of movies and this is how I implemented the rendering of the results.

```
const getAllData = async () => {
const movieData = await getMovies()
const movieContainer = movieData.map((movie)=> {
    const listItem = `
    <li class="movie">
        <img src="${movie.Poster}"></img>
        <h1>
            ${movie.Title}
        </h1>
        <h2>Release Year: ${movie.Year}</h2>
        <p>
            <button onclick="getDetails('${movie.imdbID}')">
            Click for more details
            </button>
        </p>
        </li>
    `;  
    return listItem
}).join('')
document.getElementById("movieList").innerHTML = movieContainer;
 }
```

Here is the getDetails function that the button click calls.

```
function getDetails(id){
sessionStorage.setItem('movieId', id);
window.location = 'movie.html';
return false;}
```

This code works as intended. However, what I was having trouble with is that I want to implement this logic with event listeners instead of inline HTML event-handlers. How could I implement this?
Would I need to change anything drastic about my current code?

Comment: Please be aware, this approach is vulnerable to XSS attacks via HTML string injection.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `<li>` element instead of an HTML string, then select the button descendant using `querySelector` and you can use `addEventListener`:

```
const getAllData = async () => {
    const movieData = await getMovies();
    const ul = document.getElementById("movieList");
    for (const movie of movieData) {
        const li = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
        li.className = 'movie';
        li.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${movie.Poster}"></img>
            <h1>
                ${movie.Title}
            </h1>
            <h2>Release Year: ${movie.Year}</h2>
            <p>
                <button>
                Click for more details
                </button>
            </p>
        `;
        li.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            getDetails(movie.imdbID);
        });
    }
};
```

I'd also highly recommend against direct concatenation of external input into an HTML string, like with

```
<img src="${movie.Poster}"></img>
```

unless the input is absolutely trustworthy, since that can result in arbitrary code execution, which is a security risk. If you aren't doing it already, I'd suggest either verifying that the interpolated values are well formatted (for example, without anything which would result in HTML markup, like `<script>` tags), or assign the dynamic properties/attributes after the `<li>` has been populated with the base template.

Comment: Thank you so much! I read up on the problems with directly concatenating API to html and I modified it to prevent any html attacks as well. Thank you!